# Div with dynamic content not reducing size in Chrome and Opera

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, tabs, height

I'm relatively new to Jquery, and am having a terrible time trying to get a div containing tabbed content to change it's size when the content is smaller than the div was previosuly.

There are four tab panels, and upon page load in Chrome and Opera the containing div is the same height as it would be if all of the panels were still visible. I have been able to force the div to update by opening developer tools in Chrome. Afterwards, opening the tab with more lines of content makes the container expand, but it will not resize when there is less content afterwards. Firefox, Safari, and Ie all seem to behave, but I cannot seem to figure out what is or is not happening in Chrome and Opera.

[Here is a link to an example on Codepen.](http://cdpn.io/puAem)

The #container div should shrink / expand to fit either the tabs or the tab panel, whichever is the tallest.

Answer (score 0):

Any browser acts differently, some, like Chrome mostly know what you want and the design there is easy.

anyhow, i would suggest to use `max-height, max-width, min-height, min-width` CSS properties and apply them of each of the tabbed divs.